# Jenkins & SVN Integration - pause before building + dev names

Tags: svn, jenkins

We'd like to get continous integration going where we use an SVN hook to Jenkins to create a build for every checkin.  We understand how to set this up, but would like to incorporate some specific functionality.

a) Ideally, we'd like to wait for 5 minutes or so after a commit until another commit is done to stop 2 builds from needlessly overlapping.  And then if another commit comes in within that 5 minute period, then reset the clock.

b) Is it possible to get the name of the developer who performed the checkin.  We'd like to notify them specifically if their checkin breaks something.

Thanks!

Comment: Another way of working could be to choose hourly time frame for build by making schedule as "H * * * *" and provide build URL to allow developers to build on demand.You can create a limited access user account for running builds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A) Go to Manage Jenkins -> Configure System, one of the first options is "Quiet period", which will block a job for that many minutes. You can see a full explanation [here](http://jenkins-ci.org/content/quiet-period-feature)

B) You can use the [email-ext plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin) to notify committers when a build fails

Comment: Thank you - these links addressed my questions perfectly!